# API design: separate arguments for point count and point count in units or one argument with real/complex values

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, api-design, units-of-measurement

I'm designing a set of Python functions (digital signal processing stuff like filters, spectrograms, etc.) which usually take at least one argument which could be expressed either in number of true data points or as some value in some (e.g. time axis) units. I see three options how to provide a convenient way (mostly for interactive IPython usage) to specify the target quantity:

## Option 1: separate arguments for normal and unit values

For example I could specify the critical cutoff frequency in the standard way as `f_c=0.2` which would be relative to the Nyquist frequency as usual, or I could specify it in as `f_c_s=1500` which would be e.g. 1500 kHz in the sampling frequency units kHz. Or when giving window lengths, I could give either `n_window=1000` or `n_window_s=1` which would be 1 ms in time axis units.

- advantages: the argument names give clear indication of what is used (assuming the names differ enough)
- disadvantages: the function signatures become much longer and conflicting arguments must be handled, extra argument names must be remembered by the user

## Option 2: one argument for value, second for type

Similar to Option 1, but just one argument for the value and one argument for the value type. For instance, `f_c=1500` would be in kHz units if `in_nyq=False` (it would be determined automatically) and relative to f_nyq if `in_nyq=True`. For points there would be an extra argument `in_points=True/False`.

- advantages: easier to remember, arguments and signature are explicit
- disadvantages: extra arguments in signature as in Option 1

## Option 3: use real/complex numbers to distinguish units

There would be just one function argument, but `f_c=0.2` would be relative to Nyquist, `f_c=1500j` would be in sampling frequency units. Or `n_window=1000` would be 1000 pints, `n_window=1j` would be 1 ms.

- advantages: easy to remember, very convenient for interactive usage
- disadvantages: mathematically unclean, may have to convert and check values being passed in a pipeline

Which option would you recommend? Can you see some other advantages/disadvantages? Or perhaps other options?

Comment: What about option 3 but _not_ with complex numbers as that is not really obvious.  Instead use objects with value and type information, i.e. an own data type for this argument.  Or different functions for different types of arguments (if the function takes different paths of execution depending on the type). Or helper functions to convert values with different units before calling the function.

Comment: As written in the beginning, I'm looking for a convenient way for interactive usage. Wrapping values in extra objects means writing and remembering extra code.

Comment: You could implement `__rmul__()` for the units and write it like `5*cm` or `20*hz` with `cm` and `hz` being such unit instances of value one.